# Finding $\cos2a +\cos2b+\cos2c$, if $(\tan a)^2 (\tan b)^2+(\tan b)^2(\tan c)^2+(\tan a)^2(\tan c)^2+2(\tan a)^2(\tan b)^2(\tan c)^2=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> If
> $$(\tan\alpha)^2  (\tan\beta)^2 + (\tan\beta)^2 (\tan\gamma)^2 +(\tan\alpha)^2  (\tan\gamma)^2 + 2(\tan\alpha)^2(\tan\beta)^2 (\tan\gamma)^2 = 1 $$ (where $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma$ are as per domain of $\tan x$ ). Find the value of
> $$\cos2\alpha +\cos2\beta+\cos2\gamma$$

I had got it by arbitrarily choosing some specific angles so that the given condition is satisfied. But it's a negative approach. So I am looking for more of a general approach....

So What I did is I expanded $\cos2\alpha$ in $\tan\alpha$ form and cross multiplied everything but didn't get anything.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do the three angles make a triangle? If so you should say so. Consider using $\cos 2x=\frac{1-\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}$.

Comment: No actually those angles aren't angles of triangle

Comment: I tried using the formula you mentioned but nothing is happening....

Comment: I had got it my arbitrarily choose some specific angles so that the given condition is satisfied.But it's a negative approach .So I am looking for more of a general approach....

Comment: Start with $\cos(2\alpha) = 1-2\sin^2 \alpha$, $\cos(2 \beta) = 1-2\sin^2\beta$, $\cos(2\gamma) = 1-2\sin^2 \gamma$. Adding them gives that it's enough to know $\sin^2 \alpha+\sin^2 \beta + \sin^2 \gamma$. Now see either the last post [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1486680p8705421), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262828) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557018). The approaches are general, they don't follow by guessing $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. The last post is a dupe candidate, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with $\cos(2a)+\cos(2b)+\cos(2c)$, and use
the tangent version of the double angle formula (for brevity's sake, let $A=(\tan(a))^2,B=(\tan(b))^2,C=(\tan(c))^2$)
$$\cos(2a)+\cos(2b)+\cos(2c)=\frac{1-A}{1+A}+\frac{1-B}{1+B}+\frac{1-C}{1+C}$$

Then, condense the RHS into a common denominator, and apply algebra:
$$\frac{1-A}{1+A}+\frac{1-B}{1+B}+\frac{1-C}{1+C}=\frac{(1-A)(1+B)(1+C)}{(1+A)(1+B)(1+C)}+\frac{(1+A)(1-B)(1+C)}{(1+A)(1+B)(1+C)}+\frac{(1+A)(1+B)(1-C)}{(1+A)(1+B)(1+C)}=\frac{1-A+B+C-AB-AC+BC-ABC}{1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC}+\frac{1+A-B+C-AB+AC-BC-ABC}{1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC}+\frac{1+A+B-C+AB-AC-BC-ABC}{1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC}=\frac{3+A+B+C-AB-AC-BC-3ABC}{1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC}$$

Now, we were given $AB+AC+BC+2ABC=1$.  We can manipulate the above to use this substitution to simplify:
$$\frac{3+A+B+C-AB-AC-BC-3ABC}{1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC}=\frac{3+A+B+C-AB-AC-BC-ABC-2ABC}{1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC+ABC-ABC}=\frac{3+A+B+C-(AB+AC+BC+2ABC)-ABC}{1+A+B+C+(AB+AC+BC+2ABC)-ABC}=\frac{3+A+B+C-1-ABC}{1+A+B+C+1-ABC}=\frac{2+A+B+C-ABC}{2+A+B+C-ABC}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

By $\cos 2x=\frac{1-\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}$, and let $a^2=\tan^2\alpha, b^2=\tan^2\beta, c^2= \tan^2\gamma$, we have:

\begin{align}
\cos2\alpha +\cos2\beta+\cos2\gamma
&=\frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{1-c^2}{1+c^2}\\
&=-3+2(\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+c^2})\\
\end{align}
For $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+c^2}$, we have:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+c^2}
&=\frac{3+2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^2b^2c^2}{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)}
\end{align}

By the given condition, we have:
\begin{align}
(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)&=1+a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^2b^2c^2\\
&=2+a^2+b^2+c^2-a^2b^2c^2
\end{align}

We can do the same thing on the numerator, and the final answer is 1